# iOS: Using UIView's 'drawRect:' vs. its layer's delegate 'drawLayer:inContext:'

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, core-animation

I have a class which is a subclass of `UIView`. I am able to draw stuff inside the view either by implementing the `drawRect` method, or by implementing `drawLayer:inContext:` which is a delegate method of `CALayer`.

I have two questions:

1. How to decide which approach to use? Is there a use case for each one?
2. If I implement `drawLayer:inContext:`, it is called (and `drawRect` isn't, at least as far as putting a breakpoint can tell), even if I don't assign my view as the `CALayer` delegate by using:

   `[[self layer] setDelegate:self];`

   how come the delegate method is called if my instance is not defined to be the layer's delegate? and what mechanism prevents `drawRect` from being called if `drawLayer:inContext:` is called?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> How to decide which approach to use? Is there a use case for each one?

Always use `drawRect:`, and never use a `UIView` as the drawing delegate for any `CALayer`.

> how come the delegate method is called if my instance is not defined to be the layer's delegate? and what mechanism prevents drawRect from being called if `drawLayer:inContext:` is called?

Every `UIView` instance is the drawing delegate for its backing `CALayer`. That's why `[[self layer] setDelegate:self];` seemed to do nothing. It's redundant. The `drawRect:` method is effectively the drawing delegate method for the view's layer. Internally, `UIView` implements `drawLayer:inContext:` where it does some of its own stuff and then calls `drawRect:`. You can see it in the debugger:

[image: drawRect: stacktrace]

This is why `drawRect:` was never called when you implemented `drawLayer:inContext:`. It's also why you should never implement any of the `CALayer` drawing delegate methods in a custom `UIView` subclass. You should also never make any view the drawing delegate for another layer. That will cause all sorts of wackiness.

If you are implementing `drawLayer:inContext:` because you need to access the `CGContextRef`, you can get that from inside of your `drawRect:` by calling `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`.

Comment: I was implementing it as part of following Apple's code sample `AccelerometerGraph`. I guess that in that code sample they implemented `drawLayer:inContext:` since there are some layers added to the layer hierarchy besides the view's root-layer, and indeed the delegate is not the `UIView` instance.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW10 " There are also other ways to provide a view’s content, such as setting the contents of the underlying layer directly, but overriding the drawRect: method is the most common technique."

Comment: Hi Nathan, I am very new to the custom drawing in iOS. I have a subclassed UIView class where I would need to do drawing on 3 different layers over one another. I want to make first layer, draw something on it, then put second layer and draw on it and then the third. How do I accomplish it from within the UIView Subclass that I have?

Comment: +1 for "all sorts of wackiness" (and a good thorough explanation)

Comment: If you're not supposed to use a UIView as a delegate then why does apple have this line in the docs for the CALayer property 'delegate': `In iOS, if the layer is associated with a UIView object, this property must be set to the view that owns the layer. `

Comment: Any idea what "some stuff of its own" is? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746795 seems to indicate that clipping to the layer's `cornerRadius` may be one of the things that UIView declines to do if you define your own `drawRect`.

Comment: This is not correct answer. Whenever possible, we should use CAlayer instead of overriding drawRect to avoid potential performance issues. Refer Apple's WWDC 2012 video - iOS App Performance: Graphics and Animations (Link to site https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/ ). View from 11.40, where Apple engineer specifically addressed this scenario.

Comment: @user2734323 The question wasn't about the tradeoffs of using a `UIView` with `drawRect:` or a `CALayer`. It was about implementing `[CALayerDelegate drawLayer:inContext:]` in a `UIView` subclass. There are definitely cases where `drawRect:` is preferred. You even say in your comment "whenever possible". What if what the OP is drawing can't be described by declaring `CALayer` properties like a vector drawing with multiple shapes/paths, drop shadows, etc.?

Comment: Nathan, I commented on your statement "Always use drawRect:". This is not correct. Apple recommends using CALayer or drawLayer:inContext unless drawRect overriding is absolutely required. Details of that are in WWDC 2012 video. You are correct that certain cases such as vector drawing could be easily achieved by overriding drawRect (but not the only solution). However, in most cases, CALayer provides superior performance advantage over drawRect. Therefore, the answer should be "case by case basis".

Comment: "Always use `drawRect:`" was in response to the question of whether the OP should implement `drawRect:` or `drawLayer:inContext:` in a `UIView` subclass. I can't think of a single good reason to implement `drawLayer:inContext:` in a `UIView` subclass. As for using `CALayer` (and its subclasses) whenever possible, I completely agree, and I've been preaching that gospel since at least 2009. Proof here: https://github.com/neror (warning, some of that stuff is pretty *old*) :)

Comment: I agree with @user2734323, this is not the correct answer, even in apple example projects they recommend using drawLayer:inContext: over drawRect.
For people later looking for this you answer may be misleading. You should at least add a clarification.

Comment: The two functions serve different purposes. Check my answer below: stackoverflow.com/a/36050120/1183577

Answer (score 44):

`drawRect` should only be implemented when absolutely needed. The default implementation of `drawRect` includes a number of smart optimizations, like intelligently caching the view's rendering. Overriding it circumvents all of those optimizations. That's bad. Using the layer drawing methods effectively will almost always outperform a custom `drawRect`. Apple uses a `UIView` as the delegate for a `CALayer` often - in fact, every [UIView is the delegate of it's layer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layer). You can see how to customize the layer drawing inside a UIView in several Apple samples including (at this time) ZoomingPDFViewer.

While the use of `drawRect` is common, it's a practice that has been discouraged since at least 2002/2003, IIRC. There aren't many good reasons left to go down that path.

[Advanced Performance Optimization on iPhone OS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) (slide 15)

[Core Animation Essentials](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/)

[Understanding UIKit Rendering](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/)

[Technical Q&A QA1708: Improving Image Drawing Performance on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1708/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010245)

[View Programming Guide: Optimizing View Drawing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Optimizing/Optimizing.html)

Comment: This answer contradicts the accepted answer by @NathanEror . It seems to me that the reason `drawRect` is to be avoided is that it gets called every time the view is refreshed, even if nothing has really changed; if there's no `drawRect` then Core Animation uses the layer's existing backing store which was presumably drawn earlier. But I'm desperately confused and in need of an official Apple sequence diagram... got any pointers?

Comment: See WWDC 2012 Session "iOS App Performance: Graphics and Animation" . That is probably as close as you will get to what you are looking for. https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

Comment: OMG that is a great presentation! I just leveled up... I can feel my hit points and mana increasing!

Answer (score 15):

Here're codes of Sample ZoomingPDFViewer from Apple:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)r
{

    // UIView uses the existence of -drawRect: to determine if it should allow its CALayer
    // to be invalidated, which would then lead to the layer creating a backing store and
    // -drawLayer:inContext: being called.
    // By implementing an empty -drawRect: method, we allow UIKit to continue to implement
    // this logic, while doing our real drawing work inside of -drawLayer:inContext:

}

-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: In case anyone can't really figure it out, what the comment means is that it probably compiles out the entire drawRect method if its defined but nothing in it, so its the same as not implementing drawRect at all, they just inserted it so they could explain why you don't use it. A bit confusing for me but I commented out the entire empty drawRect method and the program still works as inteded (ZoomingPDFViewer)

Comment: No... the comment means that IF -drawRect: exists, UIKit behaves differently (i.e. UIKit looks if the view respondsToSelector drawRect:, and based on that, its CALayer may or may not be invalidated).

Answer (score 9):

**Whether you use `drawLayer(_:inContext:)` or `drawRect(_:)` (or both) for custom drawing code depends on whether you need access to the current value of a layer property while it is being animated.**

I was struggling today with various rendering issues related to these two functions when implementing [my own Label class](https://github.com/fluidsonic/JetPack/blob/master/Sources/UI/Label.swift). After checking out the documentation, doing some trial-and-error, decompiling UIKit and inspecting Apple's [Custom Animatable Properties example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2284/Introduction/Intro.html) I got a good sense on how it's working.

### `drawRect(_:)`

If you don't need to access the current value of a layer/view property during its animation you can simply use `drawRect(_:)` to perform your custom drawing. Everything will work just fine.

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // your custom drawing code
}
```

### `drawLayer(_:inContext:)`

Let's say for example you want to use `backgroundColor` in your custom drawing code:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let colorForCustomDrawing = self.layer.backgroundColor
    // your custom drawing code
}
```

When you test your code you'll notice that `backgroundColor` does not return the correct (i.e. the current) value while an animation is in-flight. Instead it returns the final value (i.e. the value for when the animation is completed).

In order to get the **current** value during the animation, you must access the `backgroundColor` of the `layer` **parameter** passed to `drawLayer(_:inContext:)`. And you must also draw to the `context` **parameter**.

**It is very important to know that a view's `self.layer` and the `layer` parameter passed to `drawLayer(_:inContext:)` are not always the same layer! The latter might be a copy of the former with partial animations already applied to its properties.** That way you can access correct property values of in-flight animations.

Now the drawing works as expected:

```
override func drawLayer(layer: CALayer, inContext context: CGContext) {
    let colorForCustomDrawing = layer.backgroundColor
    // your custom drawing code
}
```

But there are two new issue: `setNeedsDisplay()` and several properties like `backgroundColor` and `opaque` do no longer work for your view. `UIView` does no longer forward calls and changes to its own layer.

`setNeedsDisplay()` does only do something if your view implements `drawRect(_:)`. It doesn't matter if the function actually does something but UIKit uses it to determine whether you do custom drawing or not.

The properties likely don't work anymore because `UIView`'s own implementation of `drawLayer(_:inContext:)` is no longer called.

So the solution is quite simple. Just call the superclass' implementation of `drawLayer(_:inContext:)` and implement an empty `drawRect(_:)`:

```
override func drawLayer(layer: CALayer, inContext context: CGContext) {
    super.drawLayer(layer, inContext: context)

    let colorForCustomDrawing = layer.backgroundColor
    // your custom drawing code
}


override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Although we use drawLayer(_:inContext:) we still need to implement this method.
    // UIKit checks for its presence when it decides whether a call to setNeedsDisplay() is forwarded to its layer.
}
```

---

### Summary

Use `drawRect(_:)` as long as you don't have the problem that properties return wrong values during an animation:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // your custom drawing code
}
```

Use `drawLayer(_:inContext:)` **and** `drawRect(_:)` if you need to access the current value of view/layer properties while they are being animated:

```
override func drawLayer(layer: CALayer, inContext context: CGContext) {
    super.drawLayer(layer, inContext: context)

    let colorForCustomDrawing = layer.backgroundColor
    // your custom drawing code
}


override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Although we use drawLayer(_:inContext:) we still need to implement this method.
    // UIKit checks for its presence when it decides whether a call to setNeedsDisplay() is forwarded to its layer.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

On iOS, the overlap between a view and its layer is very large. By default, the view is the delegate of its layer and implements the layer's `drawLayer:inContext:` method. As I understand it, `drawRect:` and `drawLayer:inContext:` are more or less equivalent in this case. Possibly, the default implementation of `drawLayer:inContext:` calls `drawRect:`, or `drawRect:` is only called if `drawLayer:inContext:` is not implemented by your subclass.

> How to decide which approach to use? Is there a use case for each one?

It doesn't really matter. To follow the convention, I would normally use `drawRect:` and reserve the use of `drawLayer:inContext:` when I actually have to draw custom sublayers that are not part of a view.

Comment: You beat me to it by a matter of seconds. :-P

Comment: @Nathan: But your answer is better than mine.

Comment: Hi Ole, I am very new to the custom drawing in iOS. I have a subclassed UIView class where I would need to do drawing on 3 different layers over one another. I want to make first layer, draw something on it, then put second layer and draw on it and then the third. How do I accomplish it from within the UIView Subclass that I have?

Comment: The two functions serve different purposes. Check my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36050120/1183577

Answer (score 2):

The [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW9) has this to say: "There are also other ways to provide a view’s content, such as setting the contents of the underlying layer directly, but overriding the drawRect: method is the most common technique."

But it doesn't go into any details, so that should be a clue: don't do it unless you really want to get your hands dirty.

The UIView's layer's delegate is pointed at the UIView. However, the UIView does behave differently depending on whether or not drawRect: is implemented. For example, if you set the properties on the layer directly (such as its background color or its corner radius), these values are overwritten if you have a drawRect: method - even if its completely empty (i.e. doesnt even call super).