# UIView overriding drawRect causes view not to obey masksToBounds

Tags: ios, uiview, ios6, drawrect

I am trying to override the `drawRect:` method of UIView in my custom view. However, my view has a border radius defined as:

```
    sub = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProfileView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self addSubview:sub];
    [sub setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    CALayer *layer = sub.layer;
    layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    layer.borderWidth = 5.0;
    layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    layer.cornerRadius = 30.0;
```

This works perfectly and places a nice border with a border radius around my view (don't mind the diagonal/straight white lines at the back, they have nothing to do with this view):

[image: correct one]

However, when I try to override the `drawRect:` method in my view, I can see a black background not masking to bounds. I don't do **anything** (currently), here is my code:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

And here is the result:

[image: incorrect one]

I've changed nothing but the draw method. How can I override the draw method while keeping my view obey the corner radius mask? Is this a bug in iOS or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the full answer, but I do know that UIView's implementation of `drawLayer:inContext:` works differently depending on whether you have implemented `drawRect:` or not. Perhaps masking/clipping to bounds is one of those things it does differently.

You can try solving your issue a number of ways:

- make your background transparent:

  ```
      layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
  ```
- clip yourself inside your custom `drawRect:`:

  ```
  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
      [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:30.0] addClip];
      [image drawInRect:rect];  // or whatever
  }
  ```
- carve out the corners explicitly:

  ```
  CGContextBeginPath(c);
  CGContextAddArc(c, r, r, r, M_PI, 3*M_PI_2, 0);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 0, 0);
  CGContextClosePath(c);
  CGContextClip(c);
  [[UIColor grayColor] setFill];
  UIRectFill(rect);
  ```

I stole those last 2 suggestions from this great presentation from WWDC 2010: [Advanced Performance Optimization on iPhone OS](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/135__advanced_performance_optimization_on_iphone_os_part_1.pdf) (video listed at [this index page](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) -- annoyingly, no direct link).

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I was recently reading a useful blog post titled [Abusing UIView](http://jimkubicek.com/blog/2012/10/11/using-uiview/). In it the author advises against overriding `drawRect` to do things like add a border when there are other ways of doing it. He says,

> Overriding `drawRect:` causes a performance hit. I haven’t profiled it,
>   so I don’t know if it’s a signifigant performance under normal
>   circumstances (it’s probably not), but in most cases, folks who
>   override `drawRect:` can accomplish what they want much easier by
>   setting properties on a view’s layer property. If you need to draw an
>   outline around a view, here’s how you would do it:
>
> ```
> #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
>
> - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
>   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
>   if (self) {
>       self.layer.borderWidth = 2.f;
>       self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
>   }
>   return self;
> ```

I realize this probably doesn't solve the problem of the black background showing through. It is just something else to think about.

Answer (score 2):

Setting

```
opaque = false // NO for ObjC
```

on the view solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you shouldn't call the

```
[super drawRect:rect]
```

inside your drawRect. [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html) that:

> If you subclass UIView directly, your implementation of this method
>   does not need to call super. However, if you are subclassing a
>   different view class, you should call super at some point in your
>   implementation.

It seems that calling the super method causes strange behaviour.