# UITextfield borderColor and width on one side of the text field

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios7, formborderstyle

I have a text field setup like so:

```
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
textField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
textField.layer.borderWidth= 10.0f;'
```

But is it possible to just have a larger border on the left side and it be a different color?
Or do I have to position a drawRect there with the color I want and position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with this code might be help's you add Border left side of custom TextFiled like Bellow:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *bottomBorder = [[UIView alloc]
                            initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,4,txtField.frame.size.height)];
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [txtField addSubview:bottomBorder];

}
```

This Bellow delegate Code for start after some space in textfield

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
    textField.leftView = paddingView;
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
}
```

OUTPUT look like this:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote [this small category](https://gist.github.com/Altimor/f48715200dc049fca69d) to easily add a border of a specified color and thickness on one side of a view. It depends on the excellent [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout), since the border resizes automatically with the view and I didn't want to write all this using Auto Layout's native API.

Just call

```
[myView addBorder:ALEdgeLeft withColor:[UIColor blueColor] width:2.0f];
```

You can call it several times to add borders on different edges.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, i font think its possible you can Set the borderStyle of your text view to `UITextBorderStyleNone` and then you can place them on top of whatever you want. In Facebook's case, it looks like they're on top of a table view, but you could put any image behind them.

Answer (score 0):

you can create one image with one sided border and set it to the `background` of your `UITextField` :

```
yourTextField.backgroundColor = 
 [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourBorderedImageName"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is adding a category on UIView, but addings borders as views instead of as CALayers so they can resize correctly using AutoresizingMasks.

Check this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29033559/1658831