# How to change layer.border.top color?

Tags: ios, border, calayer

In iOS, how can I change `layer.border.top` color? If I change `self.layer.borderColor`, all the side change. But If I only want to change one side, and keep other three sides as is, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about adding a new layer?

```
yourView.clipsToBounds = YES;

CALayer *topBorder = [CALayer layer];
topBorder.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
topBorder.borderWidth = 1;
topBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), 2);    
[yourView.layer addSublayer:topBorder];
```

replace `yourView` with whatever view is contained in your view controller that you want to add the border to.

Also, [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23157272/981049) might help you out a bit.