# How to set UITextField border/CALayer border ios on three sides only

Tags: ios, objective-c, border, calayer

I need a border to my textfield like the following image.how can i do that?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355280/how-to-add-a-border-just-on-the-top-side-of-a-uiview

Comment: use image as background and don't set border to uitextfield...

Answer (score 1):

try these..
i hope it helps...

```
UITextField *txt=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 150, 30)];
[txt setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[txt setPlaceholder:@"Hello my friend"];
[self.view addSubview:txt];


CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
border.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
border.frame = CGRectMake(0, -2, txt.frame.size.width, txt.frame.size.height);
border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
[txt.layer addSublayer:border];
txt.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I got your logic,it should be working.But its not.Dont know why

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer my own.

just pass the textfield name to the following function

```
-(void)setBorderView:(UITextField*)textField
{
    UIView *borderView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    borderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    CGRect frameRectEmail=textField.frame;


    NSLogVariable(textField);
    borderView.layer.borderWidth=1;
    borderView.layer.borderColor=[customColor colorWithHexString:@"8c8b90"].CGColor;
    borderView.layer.cornerRadius=5;
    borderView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;



    UIView *topBorder = [[UIView alloc]init];
    topBorder.backgroundColor = [customColor colorWithHexString:@"1e1a36"];
    CGRect frameRect=textField.frame;
    frameRect.size.height=CGRectGetHeight(textField.frame)/1.5;
    topBorder.frame = frameRect;
      frameRectEmail.size.width=frameRect.size.width;
    [borderView setFrame:frameRectEmail];

    [_textFieldBackGroundView addSubview:borderView];
    [_textFieldBackGroundView addSubview:topBorder];
    [_textFieldBackGroundView addSubview:textField];

}
```

I am creating a view below the textfield and setting the border to this view.Now i am creating another view with the same baground color and masking the top portion od the borderView.It is not practical in all situations.But for me,it works great.Thanks.