# Add border for view not working for ipad

Tags: ios, swift

I created extension based on this answer: [How to add a border just on the top side of a UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355280/how-to-add-a-border-just-on-the-top-side-of-a-uiview)

```
extension CALayer {

    func addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge, color: UIColor, thickness: CGFloat) {
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355280/how-to-add-a-border-just-on-the-top-side-of-a-uiview
        let border = CALayer()

        switch edge {
        case UIRectEdge.Top:
            border.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), thickness)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.Bottom:
            border.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - thickness, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), thickness)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.Left:
            border.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, thickness, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame))
            break
        case UIRectEdge.Right:
            border.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) - thickness, 0, thickness, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame))
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        border.backgroundColor = color.CGColor;

        self.addSublayer(border)
    }
}
```

But in Ipad i see only 70% border width:

[image]

I tried change `frame` to `bounds` but it not worked too.

Comment: The code looks ok to me, 1- are you zooming in or out in simulator? this can crunch some pixels, 2- do you have another object that can have white area that cover that part on the right?

Comment: I tried on real device too, the same. but on iphone ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frame of view is resized after adding border. You add border in viewDidLoad() method right? Try to add border in viewDidAppear() method:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    yourView.layer.addBorder(UIRectEdge.Top, color: UIColor.redColor(), thickness: 0.5)
}
```

Move adding layer from

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}
```

to

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.layer.addBorder(UIRectEdge.Top, color: UIColor.redColor(), thickness: 0.5)
}
```

Comment: I use this method it in table cell too

Comment: you use it in cellForRow method right? check frame of that cell. Print in console next values: print("cell width = \ (cell.frame.size.width)") and print("view width = \ (view.frame.size.width)") in cellForRow method I think your view is actually wider than cell frame. Better to move method from cellForRow to willDisplayCell method of UITableViewDelegate

Comment: @Arti can you please accept as final answer, so I will receive more reputation) i am new here and want to be able to comment, thanks!