# ios:how to add top and bottom border in tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want table like this image that show top and bottom border with color only
[image]

> i have apply this code in viewDidLoad()

```
tblFilter.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
tblFilter.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

> above code add border at all side that i dont want.
>   i want table border in only top or bottom side.
>   i want tableview border like given image. see given image.
>   please suggest me solution
>   Thanks

Comment: you can use uiview with 1px height and width same as table. and set background color of uiview

Comment: i'm new in ios so, how to add uiview at top and bottom ?

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23157272/3901620

Comment: just decrase the x and increase the width thats all, you get top and bottom only

Comment: added border but its scrolling when i scroll my tableview. i dont want to scroll border. it should be stickt to top and bottom. i apply below code     let topBorder = CAShapeLayer()
        let topPath = UIBezierPath()
        topPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        topPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tblFilter.frame.width, y: 0))
        topBorder.path = topPath.cgPath
        topBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        topBorder.lineWidth = 1.0
        topBorder.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        tblFilter.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    let topBorder = CAShapeLayer()
    let topPath = UIBezierPath()
    topPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    topPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tblFilter.frame.width, y: 0))
    topBorder.path = topPath.cgPath
    topBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    topBorder.lineWidth = 1.0
    topBorder.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    tblFilter.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)

    let bottomBorder = CAShapeLayer()
    let bottomPath = UIBezierPath()
    bottomPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: tblFilter.frame.height))
    bottomPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tblFilter.frame.width, y: tblFilter.frame.height))
    bottomBorder.path = bottomPath.cgPath
    bottomBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    bottomBorder.lineWidth = 1.0
    bottomBorder.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    tblFilter.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
```

Comment: Thanks but when i scroll my tableview its scrolling. i want fix at top and bottom. what i do ?

Comment: at  last line What does "btn" means ?

Comment: Thanks it working but when i scrolling tableview why this line scrolling with them. i dont want to scroll it.

Comment: border is Still scrolling .. what i do ? @Rajeshkumar R

Comment: @hardik Add this lines in `viewDidLoad` method `let top = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tblFilter.frame.size.width, height: 1))
        line.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        
        let bottom = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tblFilter.frame.size.width, height: 1))
        line.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        
        tblFilter.tableFooterView = bottom
        tblFilter.tableHeaderView = top`

Comment: but try to understand. as per your code view has been added on top of the tableview but when i scroll table then border also scroll with them and that i dont want. i need stickt border on top or bottom.

Answer (score 1):

my problem is solved.
i added one custom view. In that view i added two view with 1px height at top and bottom of view and i added table-view in that custom view.

Answer (score 0):

If don't want to use the table footer and header you can use the table header view and footer view where you can return view with white color and height would be 1 and width same as table width

Comment: i did that but its scrolling with table content. i want fix at top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Use tableview header and footer.

```
// in -viewDidLoad
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = ({UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 1 / UIScreen.mainScreen.scale)];
    line.backgroundColor = self.tableView.separatorColor;
    line;
});
```

Same do it for footer also.

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = ({UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 1 / UIScreen.mainScreen.scale)];
        line.backgroundColor = self.tableView.separatorColor;
        line;
    });
```

Or else just add UIVIEW to the background and set the color. That will also help.

Comment: but how to stop scrolling ?

Comment: Inside cell you are asking stick all 4 constraint top , bottom , leading , trailing.

Comment: no, i want top and bottom border for table view and i have done it but my table border scrolling when i scroll table view so, how to stop border scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Take two UIView. Give it white color.
y cordinate of top uiview is min y of uitableview and y cordinate of bottom uiview is max y of uitableview.

you can get min y and max y using `GetMaxY` and `GetMinY`.

width of both uiview are same as uitableview.

height of both uiview are 1px.

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

take label in the cell with height value as 1 and give border to it. Programmatically hide/show on your require index.