# how to put a label which has 3 side's of border

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel, border

I need to put a label in UIView which has only 3 borders visible or highlighted as shown in the below image.How do i do this in objective-c.
If example provided, it will be good.

[image]

Comment: Hey, You can try to check this link. https://ktrkathir.wordpress.com/2015/09/18/how-to-draw-or-set-a-border-for-particular-side-of-uitextfield-in-ios/comment-page-1/

Comment: Below link may be useful to you.https://stackoverflow.com/a/29033559

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CALayer *)prefix_addUpperBorder:(UIRectEdge)edge color:(UIColor *)color thickness:(CGFloat)thickness
{
    CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];

    switch (edge) {
        case UIRectEdgeTop:
            border.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), thickness);
            break;
        case UIRectEdgeBottom:
            border.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - thickness, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), thickness);
            break;
        case UIRectEdgeLeft:
            border.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, thickness, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame));
            break;
        case UIRectEdgeRight:
            border.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) - thickness, 0, thickness, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    border.backgroundColor = color.CGColor;

    [self.layer addSublayer:border];

    return border;
}
```