# I am having an issue When I am Giving Top Border to my View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I am giving Top border to my view it is not properly working. Also I am using it in collection view `cellforitematIndexPath`

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRID")

    cell.viewForTotalMB.addTopBorderWithColor(color: UIColor(red: 72/255, green: 175/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1.0), width: 1)
    cell.viewForTotalMB.layer.masksToBounds = false



    return cell!
}
```

I am using this extension for Borders

```
extension UIView {

// lbl and txtfld Border line

func addTopBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
    let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x:0,y: 0, width:self.frame.size.width, height:width)
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add code which you have written in addTopBorderWithColor

Comment: Done you can see.

Comment: I think your code is OK, but issue with frame of UI. Please check your Total MB's UI.

Comment: Already I have checked it. But I am not able to understand it . What’s happening here in my code . Or Layout

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355280/how-to-add-a-border-just-on-the-top-side-of-a-uiview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not your solution, but it’s work to find out frame of your view or some other view overlay on view.

Run your XCode project and click on **Debug View Hierarchy**. You can see there your view frame and may be find issue.

[image]