# UIView content mode acts differently when override drawRect:

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

Im learning iOS. I've been reading Apple's View programming guide.
I did the followings to try out content mode:

- I dragged a uiview into storyboard and made it my CustomView class.
- Then i changed the content mode to be **left** and set the background color to be pink color.
- Then there's a button that just simply changes the custom view's width and height to be 1.5 times bigger.

Now, i found an interesting thing:

I run this, and click the button, then:

- Case 1: If i override the draw rect method

[drawRect: overrided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArlhW.png)

Then the appearance of the view shifted down

- Case 2: Without overriding the draw rect method
  [drawRect: not overrided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bp8X.png)

The size actually increased

After doing some search online and look into Apple's document, i couldnt any relavent things except one question mention that this might have something to do with drawLayer:inContext: behave differently if override the drawRect:

Does anyone know what is going on here?

(sorry about the formatting, this is a new account and i can't post more than 2 links.)

**CODE:**
For the CustomView, just either override drawRect or without it.

```
#import "CustomView.h"
@implementation CustomView
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
//Do nothing, for case 2 i just commented out this method.
}
@end
```

For Changing the frame of customView:

```
- (IBAction)changeBound:(id)sender {
    self.customView.frame = CGRectMake(self.customView.frame.origin.x, self.customView.frame.origin.y, self.customView.frame.size.width * 1.5, self.customView.frame.size.height * 1.5);
}
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: @rmaddy Hi, i just updated the question. However i don't think the code will help anything. I'm just confused about the different behaviours with the UIView when contentMode set to left if i override drawRect method.

Comment: Is that the actual implementation of `drawRect:`? It's really empty?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes that is my implementation of drawRect. Because im just trying out stuff up. I also tried add [super drawRect:] but it still behaves differently. I think as long as I override drawRect, the custom view will behave differently from UIView (in this case is background color). I think this might have something to do with how background color is actually getting drawn in UIView.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, i think i figure out what happened:

So drawing background code is actually handled separately in `-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context`. That's why with empty `drawRect`, it still draws the background. Also, depending on the existence of `drawRect`or not(Probably by calling `respondsToSelector`?), UIView behave different in `drawLayer :inContext`.
See [Dennis Fan's answer in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9125946/2550406)